# Cellranger gives error

Tags: single-cell, bash, linux, 10x-genomics, cellranger

I am trying to run cellranger but I get fastq permission denied error

```
fi1d18@RBGO-Server2:/opt$ cellranger-atac count --id test --reference refdata-cellranger-arc-GRCh38-2020-A-2.0.0 --fastqs /data/fi1d18/Downloads/FASTQ_scATAC/ --chemistry ARC-v1
error: couldn't open MRO file
    Caused by: Permission denied (os error 13)
fi1d18@RBGO-Server2:/opt$
```

I have added the path by

```
export PATH=/opt/cellranger-atac-2.0.0:$PATH
```

And by vim I have also added the path

```
fi1d18@RBGO-Server2:/opt$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

Any help please?

Comment: Does your user have permission to read inside `opt` ? `mro` are configurations files used and read by cellranger during each steps. If they cannot be access, then the pipeline should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of those command line parameters should be accessible locations (see [here](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-atac/software/pipelines/latest/using/count#header)). Could you please add the output of the following commands:

`ls -l /data/fi1d18/Downloads/FASTQ_scATAC/ | head`

and

`ls -l refdata-cellranger-arc-GRCh38-2020-A-2.0.0 | head`

I suspect that the refdata link should be an absolute path, rather than a relative path, i.e. something like this:

```
cellranger-atac count --id test --reference /opt/refdata-cellranger-arc-GRCh38-2020-A-2.0.0 --fastqs /data/fi1d18/Downloads/FASTQ_scATAC/ --chemistry ARC-v1
```